# where to start learning programming, goal creating map apps

Tags: maps

totally newbie,
for long time I want to start learning but when I ask question I get question "for what purpose do u want to learn programming? u want make android apps? web development? etc etc".

I am totally new and dont have clue, I just want to start learning, and discover on the way what is more interesting for me. dont have clue whats the difference between android app developers or web developers.

now I have "goal" to create maps app, google maps always show wrong directions, and my country is not in their support list, they dont do changes when i report wrong streets etc. so I want to create map app or whatever its called. I want to take for example google maps source, and start recreating it, adding streets buildings, changing road directions, etc. but googling it does not help me at all, can anyone give me direction from where I should start? 3 years ago I gave up because when I followed articles i wasted months "studying" maybe absolutely not related stuff, I just need guidance. for first even it will be good to tell me where should I ask where should I search for answers, advices. which programming languages which books, or online courses, not going to pay for any courses till I have idea what I am doing. so  am after free lessons. I am forced to write tag on post... dont have clue what to write. maybe maps? thats how clueless I am.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create mapping software to publish your own maps I think a good starting point can be [ArcGIS Online](https://www.arcgis.com/home/index.html) from Esri. They offer a free resources for developers (create dev account [here](https://developers.arcgis.com/sign-up/) for free)
There is a lot of samples to learn from, and you can go through different technologies and programming languages, check [resources](https://developers.arcgis.com/resources/) page.

If you decide that you want to prepare some software components to easier collect GIS data (GIS stands for Geographic Information System) I would suggest to give a chance to QGIS application ([QGIS website](https://qgis.org/en/site/)) which is mature mapping software with plugins system on board. It bases on plugins prepared with the python language to change UX of base QGIS application. There are also a lot of samples - you can even check how existing plugins are designed because most of them is open source.

Comment: thanks for helping me but looks like I didnt describe well, for example I dont have clue what u are talking about nothing makes sense to me maybe. when I say newbie I mean total newbie, imagine u started learning German language, (in case u are familiar then any other language) u would start learning by alphabet maybe, how to write and pronounce them, and to me it seems that u are talking to me in German language already.

tried ArcGIS online but when I choose learn how to build maps, I read articles how many people left their homes during huricane. didnt  find any usefull thing there. thank

Comment: So you need to go through basics I think. I suggest to start with python language - it has really easy to remember syntax, and there are a lot of tutorials on YouTube (for example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rfscVS0vtbw). And I believe that you need to start programming and then you need to program more, and more and suddenly you will realise that you understand "a German language" same way as you know how to use your smartphone or computer.